# Why doesn't MySQL define a boolean data type?

Tags: mysql, boolean

MySQL doesn't define a distinct boolean data type, opting instead to make BOOL and BOOLEAN aliases for TINYINT(1). Why is this so?

Answer (score 6):

It's because the SQL specification didn't define one until [SQL:1999](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:1999) and it's not enforced.  MySQL's ahead of most of the pack just for allowing the keyword - MSSQL, DB2, and Oracle use BIT and some true/false constants to fake it.

(Basically it's for the same reason that, although the SQL spec states it's pronounced "[ess queue ell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886/sql-pronunciation)," everyone I know just says "sequel" because we're lazy & understand the context.)

See also: [Comparison of different SQL implementations](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#data_types-boolean)

Comment: Great link. It explains the real reason: endless discussions about how to deal with NULLs. More than 15 years later only PostgreSQL really supports it. How crazy is that for such a commonly-requested data type?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, it's because [Boolean values in MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/boolean-values.html) are just constants aliased to 1 or 0, and depend on the underlying type being used.